# Removing Alpha Band using GDAL results in black nodatafill

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

In QGIS I have saved a raster that I styled as a Rendered Image. This saves me the trouble of uploading a style on geoserver and applying the style to the geotiff. It should also decrease the file size of the raster.

However, after saving the raster as a rendered image the image has 4 bands. Band 1, 2 and 3 and an Alpha Band. Geoserver doesn't allow this and by removing the alpha band this can be fixed. This is where the problem occurs. I used the GDAL command:
***`gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 2m_2020.tif 2m_2020_new.tif`***
to remove the alpha band.

[image]

As you can see, where the background was first transparent it is now filled with black (nodata cells). And I can't seem to get rid of this black using any of the gdal commands. Nearblack and unsetnodata both havent worked for me but I might be doing it wrong. As this raster will be published as a WMS and used in a 3D viewer (Cesium) only the styled areas are wanted and the rest should be transparent. The whole process needs to be done for multiple different measurements over different years, so using a polygon mask isn't really an option as the measured area differs slightly per year.

Comment: Have you tried to assign nodata value to output?

Comment: Do you mean when saving as a rendered image from QGIS? This isn't possible for rendered images.

Comment: You can set nodata afterwards for example with gdal_edit. You cannot remove pixels from a raster image, there is always a pixel with some value in every cell of the grid.